# how to use cookies to prevent a jquery popup to after click action

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, hide, session-cookies

hello this is my first time asking a question on here, hope im not asking for too much, i created a lightbox type pop up that starts after 20 seconds, for my site, but i dont want the popup to keep reappearing if i continue browsing(session cookie), i have tried creating cookies but it seems that i am not doing it correctly. if you can help i would appreciate it very much thank you.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {

    $('.popupbox').ready(function () {
        $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
            'opacity': '.50'
        }, 300, 'linear');
        $('.box').animate({
            'opacity': '1.00'
        }, 300, 'linear');
        $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.close').click(function () {
        close_pop();
    });

    $('.backdrop').click(function () {
        close_pop();
    });
}, 20000);


if (!readCookie('hide')) {
    $('.popupbox').show();
}

function close_pop() {
    $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 300, 'linear', function () {
        $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
    });

    $.cookie('hide', true, 1, {
        path: '/'
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set/unset cookie with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery), if you need more help that the attach let me know and i'll write the solution for you in a jsFiddle.  It will be the same as the previously linked.

Comment: @abc123 thank you for the response, i have never used cookies before, so i read that, is it that im not creating the cookie correctly or that i am not making the correct function to run it? or both.

Comment: Should be able to just include the library mentioned in that post then I believe your code looks fine.  I can make a jsFiddle if needed.

Comment: @abc123 i did use the library for the jquery cookies but it seems to not have worked, i would appreciate it if you could help me with a jsFiddle if you dont mind. thank you.

Comment: Answer added, let me know if you need anymore _help_.

Comment: @abc123 my friend youre amazing! one last question, so in order for this code to work i must run it off a server right? cause im trying to run it internally and well the pop up still appears...

Comment: Nope, it is all client-side code.  The below answer worked for me in Google Chrome.  What browser are you using? I'd be happy to take a look at it in said browser.  It might not work if you just save it as an HTML file, IE URL = `file:///C:/Users/[username]/Desktop/test.html` but if you setup a website in IIS it would work.

Comment: @abc123 sorry its been like a week since i got back to you, its just that i tired entering the code into the website and it seems that that when i enter it the popup does not occur, i checked the debugger and it marks an error as "$.cookie is not a function. i dont mean to be a bother, but could you help me one more time. thank you!

Comment: @abc123 sorry its been like a week since i got back to you, its just that i tired entering the code into the website and it seems that that when i enter it the popup does not occur, i checked the debugger and it marks an error as "$.cookie is not a function, when i check the resources for cookies it marks that there are none. i dont mean to be a bother, but could you help me one more time.  thank you!

Comment: you are missing the [jquery.cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin make sure you include it.  if it is included then make sure you do the following jQuery.cookie to see if it sees that.

Comment: @abc123 i placed the plugin inside of the javascript, am i supposed to put <script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script> inside of the html as well?

Comment: Yes, unless you did what i did in my jsFiddle you'll need to do a `script include` like you mentioned. :)

Comment: @abc123 im sorry i keep annoying you but i keep try following your jsfiddle and i seem to have everything im supposed to but yet it seems to create everything but that darn cookie can i post my whole code and you look it over see if you catch something im missing?

Comment: Yes, feel free to post all your code. Also I rewrote this in basic JavaScript so you don't have to mess with jQuery if you don't want to. Let me know if you need more, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will display a `div` after 20 seconds if the user clicks inside the div or on close the div will `hide` and won't show again unless they lose their `cookies`, even on reload.

*Special Note: Unfortunately `jquery.cookie.js` plugin doesn't have a CDN so I inline included it below...please don't do this in production include it using normal script includes.*

### **DEMO: *[jQuery jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/qRBhV/)***

**HTML**

```
<div class="popupbox" style="display: none;">
    <div class="backdrop box"> 
        <span>Hello World I am a popup.</span>
        <input type="button" class="close" value="Close" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    if (!$.cookie('hide')) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.popupbox').show();
            $('.popupbox').ready(function () {
                $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
                    'opacity': '.50'
                }, 300, 'linear');
                $('.box').animate({
                    'opacity': '1.00'
                }, 300, 'linear');
                $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
            });

            $('.close').click(function () {
                close_pop();
            });

            $('.backdrop').click(function () {
                close_pop();
            });
        }, 20000);
    }
});


function close_pop() {
    $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 300, 'linear', function () {
        $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
    });

    $.cookie('hide', true);
    return false;
}

/*!
 * jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.3.1
 * https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Klaus Hartl
 * Released under the MIT license
 */
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        // Browser globals.
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {

    var pluses = /\+/g;

    function raw(s) {
        return s;
    }

    function decoded(s) {
        return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
    }

    function converted(s) {
        if (s.indexOf('"') === 0) {
            // This is a quoted cookie as according to RFC2068, unescape
            s = s.slice(1, -1).replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
        }
        try {
            return config.json ? JSON.parse(s) : s;
        } catch (er) {}
    }

    var config = $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

        // write
        if (value !== undefined) {
            options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, options);

            if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                var days = options.expires,
                    t = options.expires = new Date();
                t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
            }

            value = config.json ? JSON.stringify(value) : String(value);

            return (document.cookie = [
            config.raw ? key : encodeURIComponent(key),
                '=',
            config.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
            options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
            options.secure ? '; secure' : ''].join(''));
        }

        // read
        var decode = config.raw ? raw : decoded;
        var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
        var result = key ? undefined : {};
        for (var i = 0, l = cookies.length; i < l; i++) {
            var parts = cookies[i].split('=');
            var name = decode(parts.shift());
            var cookie = decode(parts.join('='));

            if (key && key === name) {
                result = converted(cookie);
                break;
            }

            if (!key) {
                result[name] = converted(cookie);
            }
        }

        return result;
    };

    config.defaults = {};

    $.removeCookie = function (key, options) {
        if ($.cookie(key) !== undefined) {
            // Must not alter options, thus extending a fresh object...
            $.cookie(key, '', $.extend({}, options, {
                expires: -1
            }));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

}));
```

### DEMO: [JavaScript jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/qRBhV/8/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="popupbox" style="display: none;">
    <div class="backdrop box"> 
        <span>Hello World I am a popup.</span>
        <input type="button" class="close" value="Close" onclick="close_pop()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function close_pop() {
    $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 300, 'linear', function () {
        $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
    });

    setCookie('hide', true, 365);
    return false;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_value = null;
    } else {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

window.onload=function () {
    if (!getCookie('hide')) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.popupbox').show();
            $('.popupbox').ready(function () {
                $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
                    'opacity': '.50'
                }, 300, 'linear');
                $('.box').animate({
                    'opacity': '1.00'
                }, 300, 'linear');
                $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
            });

            $('.close').click(function () {
                close_pop();
            });

            $('.backdrop').click(function () {
                close_pop();
            });
            //change 1000 to 20000 for 20 seconds
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: turns out we had been doing it right the whole time, it was just that the server was running the code on a different engine and was throwing the whole code off! thank you once again!

Comment: @MysteryWhy more than happy to help, glad it all got worked out.

Comment: working fine, how i will set expire cookie on browser close.

Comment: @dineshkashera `<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">`